# what is the difference between service cloud and service console in salesforce

Tags: service-cloud-console, servicecloud, service-console

Can someone please help me understand what the difference is between these two things?  If I have purchased service cloud - would I see this in the list of APPS?

Comment: Hi Robin, you want might to search for Service console in the [H&T Portal](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=console2_about.htm&type=0) rather than opening a post in this forum. take some time to visit [ask] and take the [tour] in order to get familiar. Welcome to SFSE!

Answer (score 2):

**Service Cloud** is your whole Salesforce instance / org.

**Service Console** is just one of the Apps in your Service Cloud. You can access Service console from Apps.  It is a tab-based workspace that lets you manage multiple records on a single screen.

The first screenshot (1) is normal page layout.  The 2nd one is your service console.

[image]